# How many 1's are we expected to get in dice generated sequence?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, dice

We are throwing a regular dice until we get a sequence of 1,2,3. What is expected amount of 1's in the result of our dice rolling experiment ?

Comment: If you're a good magician then the answer is as many as you want.

Comment: What are your own thoughts so far?

Comment: @Théophile no sure really. I know that we can calculate expected amount of rolls till we get a sequence 1,2,3 , by using basic Markov-chains. Not sure if it is of any help in counting 1's.

Comment: I think if you can calculate the expected number of rolls, you can directly calculate the expected numbers of 1's (it'll just be one-sixth of the expected number of rolls). I could be wrong tho

Answer (score 5):

Let $X_0$ be the total number of 1s. Let $X_{1}$ be the total number of $1s$ after a $1.$ Let $X_{12}$ be tot total number of 1s after a $12.$ Then:

$$\begin{align}
E(X_0)&=\frac16(E(X_1)+1)+\frac56 E(X_0)\\
E(X_1)&=\frac16(E(X_1)+1)+\frac16E(X_{12})+\frac46E(X_0)\\
E(X_{12})&=\frac16(E(X_1)+1)+\frac46 E(X_0)
\end{align}$$

Solve for $E(X_0).$

---

The answer can also be gotten by noticing that each time a $1$ occurs, the probability it is the last $1$ is $1/36.$

Answer (score 1):

Since the time $T$ until we see the sequence of 1,2,3 is a stopping time for the sequence of die rolls, by [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) we can just multiply $\mathbb E[T]$ by $\frac16$: the expected number of 1's from each die roll.